# How to hide the login window after DocuSign finish click

Tags: docusignapi

I do not want to display pop-up after DocuSign finish click button. Can you please help me to resolve this problem.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: provide something which you have done first. Code or File.

Comment: what do you mean by done first, simply on finish button click i want to redirect to brand redirect url rather than displaying this pop up window.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog box shown depends on if the recipient has a DocuSign account, and there is no way to disable this popup. If user clicks `No Thanks` then DocuSign will automatically redirect the browser to the Brand's Redirect URL.

Comment: Ok, but my requirement was, not to display this pop up after finish click, so to resolve this i used embedded signing process, but signing document url link is expired with in 5 minutes.So now i am trying to resolve this session time out problem. Thanks

Comment: Please see my response in [49990439](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49990439/3530898) to know how to use embedded signing process. You should only generate this link when Signer is ready and all set to sign the document. You should never generate link in advance, instead invite Signer to your App and should have `Sign It` button or link on your App, and once Signer clicks it then generate the URL, and redirect user to signing page.