# Docu Sign Recipient View Url Session Time Out

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting recipient view url in docu sign embedded signing url process, but this url is expired with in 5 minutes.Please help me to increate this session time out.

Comment: If you have opened a new qs, then mark your other qs [49974086](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974086/how-to-hide-the-login-window-after-docusign-finish-click) as answered. Do not ask same qs at multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

In `embedded Signing`, you need to invite or ask your signer to visit your App, and when signer is ready to sign the document then at that time you should generate the signing URL (on-demand) and ask user to complete the signing. This link is one time use and by default, it expires in `300 seconds` if not used. If you want DocuSign to send an email to the signer with your App URL so that signer is redirected to your App when he/she clicks the email link, then you can put your App URL in the `embeddedRecipientStartURL` property of the signer in the API call. By adding this property DocuSign will send an email to DocuSign and on click on Review Documents button, browser will be redirected to your App, once it reaches your App then you can generate embedded Signing URL so that you can host the Signing ceremony.

You should never send this embedded Signing URL link in an email or via any medium. Also by default this URL timesout in `300 seconds`, but you can contact your DocuSign Account Manager or DS Support to increase it to `900 seconds` at the max. But this should only be done if your flow to generate URL is correct as explained above. Never generate this URL in advance, only generate when you want Signer to start the signing ceremony, and directly redirect the Signer to this signing page.

Comment: Ok, but when i use remote url process, then what will be max session time out ?

Answer (score 0):

If you think you need an embedded signing URL with a lifetime greater than the default 300 seconds then you most probably have a mistake in your application flow.

In addition to Amit's excellent comments, here's a solution if you want to distribute a "signing URL" via email or somesuch: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64488510/64904