# Remote + Embedded Signature

Tags: spring-boot, docusignapi, hellosign-api, e-signature

I want to build a system where a document is to be signed by the user. It may be the case that user takes 10 days to sign the document or even in minutes things are done.

Using Remote signing : User will receive the mail from third party app, and the validity of that signing link is long like 10-15 days.

Using Embedded signing : User will have to sign the document within minutes. No mail is received from 3rd party app.

I want to have a hybrid kind of system, where our system should send the mail containing the signing link to user and that link should be valid for 10-15 days.

There are workarounds for my use requirements. But I want a robust and proper solution for this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please upvote useful answers and check (accept) the best one.

Answer (score 0):

You want your app to send the email and control the validity time for the link. You also, it appears, want to use embedded signing. All of the above is straight forward with DocuSign. See my [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64488509/64904) on how to create long lived embedded signing links.

[I work for DocuSign]

### Re: embed UI in our app?

You can update your app to iFrame DocuSign's Signing Ceremony, redirect to it, or open a new browser tab for the signing ceremony.

iFraming is not recommended since it does not enable signers to assure themselves that they're using DocuSign. If you do use an iFrame, the DocuSign Signing Ceremony must receive 100% of the width and height to provide the best signing experience (especially on mobiles).

You can *brand* the DocuSign signing ceremony to include your app's logo and match your app's colors, fonts, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Larry K. Could you also provide some insights how we can embed UI in our app?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Also I need a feature in which a document is generated and mailed to respective people. In this doc we don;t need any signatures, rather we just want that document to be reviewed by the respective people. As a result the guy can accept/decline the doc sent for review.

Is this flow possible in Docusign?  @Larry K

Comment: @MasterDeveloper -- yes. Please ask as a new question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above is easily achievable with the HelloSign API. In both cases the signing link is generated right when the user launches the document to sign so there's no risk for it to expire.

Non-embedded signing: with one API call, HelloSign will send an email to the user with the link to launch the document, an email reminder if the user takes long to sign, and an email with the link to download the final document once signed. The link the user gets can only expire if the document is manually marked as cancelled (or declined by the user).

Embedded signing: in 3 API calls you are able to create the document, generate the link for the document once the signer is ready to sign in your workflow, and download the completed document for you and the user. The API uses webhooks to inform you of events during the document lifecycle, and you have the ability to handle all notifications to the user as well as the timing for each API call.

Hope this helps! Let know if you'd like me to expand on the above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @algorozco. Could you also provide some insights how we can embed UI in our app like for creating template,document?

Comment: I'd encourage you to give an eye to these:
To embed the "prepare and send document" experience: https://app.hellosign.com/api/embeddedRequestingWalkthrough

To embed the "create template" experience: https://app.hellosign.com/api/embeddedTemplatesWalkthrough

It's essentially the same but different endpoints.

Comment: Also I need a feature in which a document is generated and mailed to respective people. In this doc we don;t need any signatures, rather we just want that document to be reviewed by the respective people. As a result the guy can accept/decline the doc sent for review.

Is this flow possible in HelloSign? @algorozco